# Crontab is not working

Tags: bash, scripts, display, cron

Below is the content of my crontab:

```
toto@toto-pc:~$ crontab -l
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').
# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command

21 15 * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/freefilesync /home/toto/Backup_launch/Backup_on_My_Passport.ffs_batch >/home/toto/crontab_log 2>&1
*/10 * * * * /home/toto/Backup_launch/Backup_on_OneDrive.sh

toto@toto-pc:~$
```

Then, I expect the *Backup_on_My_Passport.ffs_batch* batch job to be executed by FreeFileSync daily at 15:21 and the script *Backup_on_OneDrive.sh* to be executed every 10 minutes.

*Backup_on_OneDrive.sh* is correctly executed every 10 minutes but crontab never starts *Backup_on_My_Passport.ffs_batch*.

Here is the content of the *crontab_log* file:

```
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified

15:21:01: Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?
```

I think the value of DISPLAY is correct:

```
toto@toto-pc:~$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
toto@toto-pc:~$
```

Comment: Excellent idea! Please see the edits in my post.

Comment: It should probably be `export DISPLAY=:1 &&` and not 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with Wayland. Then, in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf, I uncommented the line `#WaylandEnable=false` to force the login screen to use Xorg.

I then had to change `DISPLAY=:0` by `DISPLAY=:1` because `echo $DISPLAY` return `1`.

It is now working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Since `cron` passes the command line portion of the `crontab` entry to `/bin/sh` (which may be a link to `/bin/dash`), which is a simpler shell, one *should* 1) Wrap your command in a `#!/bin/bash` script; 2) Invoke the script from your `crontab`. This will make debugging, condutionals, logging, etc much easier, and you'll NEVER have to worry about `bash` features that `sh` doesn't support.

You might also benefit from my answer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673908/why-crontab-doesnt-execute-a-scheduled-bash-script/673918#673918).